# How to send cookies separately in Python with urllib2

Tags: cookies, urllib2

I'm trying to send multiple cookies to a url until I get the right one and I don't know why my current code isn't working

I've looked at the existing answers for sending cookies to a url but none of them seem to work in my case
The comments in the code are instructions for the task

```
    # Write a script that can guess cookie values
    # and send them to the url http://127.0.0.1:8082/cookiestore
    # Read the response from the right cookie value to get the flag.
    # The cookie id the aliens are using is alien_id
    # the id is a number between 1 and 75 


    import urllib2

    req = urllib2.Request('http://127.0.0.1:8082/cookiestore')
    for i in range(75):
      req.add_header('alien_id', i)
      response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
      html = response.read()  
      print(html)
```

I expected that one of the iterations would print something different, but they are all the same

Comment: Did u find solution?

Comment: @Miffy It's below ;)  Or at least it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This code is Python 3.8 as Python 2.7 is no longer supported, and your `req.add_header` line did need modifying.  Here is your solution:

```
import urllib.request

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8082/cookiestore"
y = 5

for i in range(75):
 request = urllib.request.Request(url)
 request.add_header("Cookie", "alien_id = "+str(i))
 response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
 responseStr = str(response.read().decode("utf-8"))
 print(responseStr)
```

If you are still using Python 2.7, you can just copy the `request.add_header` line. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ahaha cyber discovery i see ;) 
You were very close, infact i used your code as my base except for the add header line.
Not sure if you even still need to know but ill leave this here for others

When you send a cookie as a header you send it like so:

```py
req.add_header('Cookie', 'cookiename=cookievalue')
```

Hope this helps :D